# I want to play first video in flutter listview.builer on scroll like youtube

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, youtube

I want to play the first video in flutter listview like youtube. when the user scrolls, the video on top should play on scrolling like youtube's main screen.
on scrolling like a Youtube screen the video on top must play.
if anyone knows how to do that in a flutter, please let me know.
**Youtube main Screen**

Comment: Please provide a minimal code of your issue.

Comment: i want to play first video on top on scroll like youtube.and if video is not on top show thumbnail of video same as youtube play first video on scroll top .
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgWXC.jpg

Comment: as you can check on youtube if we scroll the first video on top play automatically and if scroll more the video who appears first it plays

Comment: @AmeerSafdar you need a scroll controller and attach it to your listview. then you need to determine the position (measurement) on the screen in which you want your video to start playing. Also remember that the position you choose has to be for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution although I did not include the video player widget:

**NOTE**: You need to consider different screen sizes while doing this and I also believe this answer can be improved. This is just demo.

**Step 1:**
Create your Video widget and make sure you know the total height it contains. In my case a total height of 250 pixels:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyVideoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isPositioned;
  String videoUrl, thumbNailUrl;
  int index;

  MyVideoWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.isPositioned,
    required this.index,
    required this.videoUrl,
    required this.thumbNailUrl,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyVideoWidget> createState() => _MyVideoWidgetState();
}

class _MyVideoWidgetState extends State<MyVideoWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
            height: 200, // height --> 1
            color: widget.isPositioned ? Colors.red : Colors.black,
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
              widget.isPositioned ? widget.videoUrl : widget.thumbNailUrl,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ))),
        SizedBox(height: 50 // height --> 2, 
                 child: Text("Video Name: ${widget.index}"))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Step 2:** Set up your home page:

- Check the number of video widgets that can fit into a phone screen or view port. For my case, it was only two that could fit which means `250 * 2 = 500`.
- Get the total height of the screen `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`. For my case, it was 640 pixels in height.
- Subtract the total number of video widgets that can fit in a screen from the screen height. `640 - 500 = 140`.

Another way to do the above steps is **(For the sake of other phone sizes)** `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / Total height of a video player widget`. In my case, `640/250 = 2.56` which means only `2 video widgets`. Then `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - (2 * 250) = 140 { 140 is the remaining space}.`

- Then on your VideoWidget add a bool flag (In my case `isPositioned`) that you can use to activate the video player once a user scrolls to position.
- Add the following parameters to get isPositioned:  `_offset <= (250 * index) && _offset >= (250 * index) - 140`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'video_widget.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<String> _videoUrls = [
    "video_1",
    "video_2",
    "video_3",
    "video_4",
    "video_5",
    "video_6"
  ];

  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  double _offset = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_function);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Screen height:${MediaQuery.of(context).size.height} ");

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _videoUrls.length,
            addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
            controller: _scrollController,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              print(
                  " $index: Offset ($_offset) is between  ${(250 * index) - 140} and  ${(250 * index)}");

              return MyVideoWidget(
                videoUrl: _videoUrls[index],
                index: index,
                thumbNailUrl: "thumbNail_$index",
                isPositioned:
                    _offset <= (250 * index) && _offset >= (250 * index) - 140,
                key: ObjectKey(_videoUrls[index]),
              );
            }));
  }

  _function() {
    // The offset is mainly on the Y-axis (i.e x = 0) since it is a vertical list
    if (mounted)
      setState(() {
        _offset = _scrollController.offset;
      });
  }
}
```